# Using NoScript to block plugins (such as Flash) without blocking JavaScript

Tags: firefox

I am looking for a way to configure NoScript in Firefox to block all plugins (Flash, Java, Silverlight, Shockwave, etc.) without blocking JavaScript, but the default options only seem to allow the possibility of blocking JavaScript *plus* plugins.

How can I leave JavaScript enabled and just block plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need NoScript to do this.  You can just go to Tools/Add-ons, click on the plugin icon (blue cube with four bumps that looks like a Lego brick), and change the settings on each plugin from "Always activate" to "Ask to activate".  Firefox will then prompt you before activating the plugins.

You can also use a different add-on than NoScript.  Flashblock is an add-on that allows you to selectively block Flash, Silverlight, and HTML5 video on a per-site basis.

NoScript is a great tool, but it's not the only tool in the toolbox.

Comment: "Ask to activate" might be the most annoying feature ever created. But it also doesn't help for YouTube; if flash is enabled at all, you can't use HTML5 video. But I would also like to be able to control plugins on a per-site basis if needed. Flashblock also only blocks Macromedia plugins.